# How do I count cells that are between two numbers in Excel?

Tags: excel, range, formula

I need a formula to count the number of cells in a range that are between 10 and 10.000:

I have:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B292,>10 AND <10.000)
```

But how do I put the comparison operators in without getting a formula error?

Comment: I feel excell should support the use of AND operators in CounfIF functions. It's so annoying and illogical why they wont. MS, stop giving us crappy UI changes and fix what really needs fixing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have Excel 2007 or later use `COUNTIFS` with an "S" on the end, i.e.

`=COUNTIFS(B2:B292,">10",B2:B292,"<10000")`

You may need to change commas , to semi-colons ;

In earlier versions of excel use `SUMPRODUCT` like this

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B292>10)*(B2:B292<10000))`

Note: if you want to include exactly 10 change > to >= - similarly with 10000, change < to <=

Answer (score 1):

Example-

For cells containing the values between 21-31, the formula is:

```
=COUNTIF(M$7:M$83,">21")-COUNTIF(M$7:M$83,">31")
```

Answer (score 0):

=COUNTIFS(H5:H21000,">=100", H5:H21000,"<999")

Comment: How is this different from the existing answers?